# Can i attach an application (say Microsoft edge) to the Hololens camera using unity to make the application follow me??

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

My goal is to make an application follow me (where i look the application is in front of me), i know that is not achievable if the application does not have the follow option. My question is, can i using Unity and scripts attach the Hololens Camera to an application such as Microsoft edge?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do something in the Shell (the initial room). At that point, I doubt a Unity app can control anything as it is the OS. I could be wrong

Comment: You should read about `billboarding` and `tag along` in holo lens